# Changing link styles in RoR 3.2.3 with bootstrap-sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the link colors in RoR 3.2.3 with Bootstrap-Sass. i've tried to add a rule in my custom.css.scss but it isn't working.  Did a search and read something about /vendors/assets/stylesheets/variables.css.scss but this file doesn't appear in the /vendors/../stylesheets directory.  Any ideas?

Comment: @PaulSimpson Thanks, I just realised this, apologies for not playing fair!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `custom.css.scss` file you created, you need to set the [bootstrap variables](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#variables) *before* you `@import "bootstrap"`(it is important to note that the variables in the twitter documentation are using LESS style syntax not Sass/SCSS). For instance, if you wanted bright red links that changed to black on hover, you would place this in your `custom.css.scss`

```
$linkColor:      #FF0000;
$linkColorHover: #000;

@import "bootstrap";
```

The variables must be defined before the import otherwise the default values are used.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense.  My understanding is that when using bootstrap-sass most variables can be changed by simply replacing the @ with a $ is this correct?

Comment: Right - @ is LESS style, $ is Sass/SCSS. You just have to make sure you place the variable definitions before the @import statement.

Comment: Still its not working for me.   
i have given   
$bodyBackground:        #fbfbfb !default;  
$textColor:             #FFF !default;  

@import "bootstrap";     

Are these variables not supported / true ones.

Answer (score 1):

One additional thing to note.  If you see your colors not being updated even after you have added the variable changes before the @import "bootstrap"; statement.  Check to make sure you don't have other files in the stylesheets directory that are overriding the bootstrap ones.  I had this issue, then when I removed the other file, I could finally see my bootstrap color changes.

Comment: This was also an issue I had built a scaffold that included a scaffold.css.scss that was causing issues, deleted it and everything worked!!